# Get the closest ancestor from current event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom, ecmascript-6

I'm having trouble selecting a closest `<tr>` element from a click event.

Currently, to make it work I select an exact number of elements in the list from `event.path`.

I would like it to be more flexible without needing to depend on the current path position number.

HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td class="col-site">Stringname</td>
</tr>
```

JavaScript:

```
event.path[1].classList.add(this.openedClassState);
```

Using [`event.closest('tr')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) is not working, and I get this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: event.closest is not a function

Does anyone know why?

Comment: @void - please see this link: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest

Comment: Is it really saying `event.closest`?

Comment: It looks like you're calling `event.closest`. Did you mean to do `element.closest`, or perhaps `event.target.closest`?

Comment: Post the actual code that is not working

Comment: It says `event.closest `, doesn't sound good, please check your code. Also, native Element.closest compatibility can be tricky, what is you environment?

Comment: There is almost certainly a better way to do this with Vue. Possibly explain what you are trying to accomplish overall instead of the implementation detail.

Comment: Sorry for the bad explanation guys, it was `event` actually. So the answer was like @JordanRunning said - `event.target.closest`

Comment: @JordanRunning - could you please move your suggestion to answer ? So I will accept it. Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you're calling `event.closest`, which doesn't seem right. Did you mean to do `element.closest`, or perhaps `event.target.closest`?

```js
function handleClick(event) {
  const tr = event.target.closest('tr');
  tr.style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}


document.querySelectorAll('td').forEach(td => 
  td.addEventListener('click', handleClick));
```

```css
td{border:1px solid blue}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Click</td>
    <td>me</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no `closest` method on the `Event` object. You need to either look for `event.target.closest` or just cache the reference to the element you're binding your event listener to, then use the `closest` method for that element.

```js
const tds = document.querySelectorAll('td');

for(const td of tds) {
  td.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log(event.target.closest('tr').id);
    console.log(td.closest('tr').id); // this does the same thing
  }, false);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr id="TR1">
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR2">
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="TR3">
    <td>Some text</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```